# Using ChannelFactory<T> To Create Channels with Different Credentials

Tags: .net, wcf, channelfactory

I am using the `ChannelFactory<T>` type to create channels into a `WsHttpBinding` WCF web service, and the service uses a username/password combination to authenticate. While I have the authentication working using my custom validator, I am having difficulty creating channels with differing credentials.

Given the overhead of creating `ChannelFactory<T>`, I'm trying to cache a single instance of it and share it for the creation of multiple channels over the lifetime of my application. Unfortunately, it seems like the credentials are directly tied to the factory and cannot be changed after a channel has been created.

In other words, if I try this:

```
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "Bob";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var channel1 = factory.CreateChannel();

factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "Alice"; // exception here
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var channel1 = factory.CreateChannel();
```

I get an exception telling me that the `UserName` property is now read-only.

Is it possible to implement any sort of caching here, or am I essentially going to have to cache an instance of `ChannelFactory` for every username?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.credentials.aspx) this is not directly possible (`Credentials` become readonly upon `Open` of the `ChannelFactory`)... if you really want to do this you will need to trick the `ChannelFactory` like this:

```
// step one - find and remove default endpoint behavior 
var defaultCredentials = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials); 


// step two - instantiate your credentials
ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
loginCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password123";


// step three - set that as new endpoint behavior on factory
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials); //add required ones
```

Another option seems to be to `Close()` the `ChannelFactory` before trying to change the `Credentials` .

Otherwise just stick with caching different ChannelFactories for different Credentials...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've ended up just creating new factories rather than deal with it.

Comment: How this can be done in code ? <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
   </security>

Comment: If you have access to Juval Lowy's ServiceModelEx library you can just call factory.SetCredentials(domain, username, password) and it apparently does the same thing as the code above. Works like a charm, if you can get the password. That's my current quest.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a new channel factory. When the factory creates the first channel, its properties become read-only (some throw the exception as you see; some others are worse in which you change but nothing happens, for example if you change some property in a binding element which you passed to the CF constructor).